# Spring boot Jar to war

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to change the spring music application (https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/spring-music) from jar to war file to test in Liberty.
I did the following change

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

and also build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'
dependencies {
    // Spring Boot
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
}
```

The war files get created,but while trying to access the application,it gives the error
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: did you try using Jar file. it might have same issue with jar also,

Comment: yes jar is also giving error after I make this modification.Though I made the changes based on doc :https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/ 

 http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging 

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Comment: please post the config class here  you are using or the class where beans are initialized.

Comment: The following is the modified Application class

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CrudRepository you need to add a dependency to 
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa like

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
```