# Spring Boot WAR generator

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, war

I have several applications written with Spring.
Recently I discovered https://start.spring.io, which builds base application jar. But I cat run this jar just with cmd command as stand alone application. However in much cases the developer need to deploy Spring application with some java web server as Jetty.
I found this question: [Spring boot Jar to war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044797/spring-boot-jar-to-war) however there gradle is used.
I use Maven and NetBeans IDE.
Even if I will change `pom.xml` using something like further code, I will need to remove and recreate the project for NetBeans, for it will handle it as WAR and not JAR application.
Is there some nice and useful utility for create WAR Spring (with Spring Boot features) Maven assembly?

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <jvmArguments>
                -Xdebug 
            -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
              </jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>mailru</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Just change `jar` to `war` in your `pom.xml`... That is the only change you need to make. The war is as much executable as the jar is.

Comment: Are all the annotation for Spring Boot relevant for Jetty container?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be? It doesn't matter which container you deploy to.

Comment: In any case, instead of randomly making guesses and searching the web, read the official Spring-Boot documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the tag `<packaging>jar</packaging>` to `<packaging>war</packaging>` within the `<project></project>` tag in your `pom.xml`. This would generate the artifact as `war`, which can be deployed in any server(tomcat or jetty etc). The spring related annotations are not specific to the web server you deploy your app on, and can run on any server without any changes.